# Django 1.7 error NoReverseMatch at '/post/'

Tags: python, django

i am newbie in django.
I was encountered below error message exception value.

```
Reverse for 'category_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

error during template rendering

```
Reverse for 'category_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

in line:

```
 <li><a href="{% url 'category_detail' pk=category.pk %}/">{{ cat.title }}</a></li>
```

djangogirls/apsi/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
)
```

djangogirls/blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
```

from . import views

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^post/$', views.post_list),
        url(r'^category/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.category_detail, name='category_detail'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail),
        url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),

)
```

djangogirls/blog/views.py

```
def category_detail(request, pk):
category = Post.objects.filter(category__id=pk)
return render(request, 'blog/category_detail.html', {'category': category})


def post_list(request):
    posts       = Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=False).order_by('published_date')
    categories  = Category.objects.all()
    tags        = Tag.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts, 'categories': categories, 'tags':tags })
```

djangogirls/blog/models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):

    title           = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug            = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description     = models.TextField()
    created_date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date  = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Post(models.Model):

    author          = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    category        = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text            = models.TextField()
    created_date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date  = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    likes           = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    thumbnail       = models.FileField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your variable names, you are using `cat` to get the title and `category` to get the pk. Maybe `category` is undefined? This will result in an empty string inserted in the url tag and would lead to the received error message.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the parameter in your `urls.py` is `pk`:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.category_detail, name='category'),
```

But you are trying to find url with parameter `category_id`.  Change it to:

```
{% url 'blog.views.category_detail' pk=category.pk %}
```

Or even omit the name of parameter:

```
{% url 'blog.views.category_detail' category.pk %}
```

And imho, as far as your url has a `name`, it is better to find this url by it's name instead of view's name:

```
{% url 'category' category.pk %}
```

**UPDATE**: In the `post_list.html` you use this code:

```
<a href="{% url 'category_detail' pk=category.pk %}/">{{ cat.title }}</a>
```

As far as I understand the category variable is named `cat`. Yous should pass the correct variable to the `{% url %}` tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'category_detail' pk=cat.pk %}">{{ cat.title }}</a>
```

To solve such problems once and forever consider to implement the [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method in your `Category` model.  Use this method any time you need to point to the category:

```
<a href="{{ cat.get_absolute_url }}">{{ cat.title }}</a>
```

Comment: thanks its work when i try url "/category/" but show another error "NoReverseMatch at /post/

Reverse for 'category' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']"