# urls.py cannot direct in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

i have want to make list category in my blog and view category

this is view.py

```
def view_category(request, pk):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=pk)
    return render_to_response('blog/category_detail.html', {
        'category': category,
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'tags': Tag.objects.all(),
        'posts': Post.objects.filter(category__id=pk)
    })


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=False).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {
        'posts': posts,
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'tags': Tag.objects.all(),
    })

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

this is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^post/all/$', views.post_list, name='index'),
    url(r'^post/category/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.view_category, name='view_blog_category'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail),

)
```

but i getting error like this

```
Exception Value: Reverse for 'view_blog_category' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/category/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

this is line error:

```
{% for cat in categories %}
   <li><a href="{% url 'view_blog_category' pk=category.pk %}">{{ cat.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

so, can you help me find solution in this probelm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621839/django-1-7-error-noreversematch-at-post) you are using the wrong variable. Use `cat.pk` in the url tag and your problem should be solved.